# Warning message: Ignoring unknown parameters: withd

Tags: r

Estoy intentando hacer un grafico de barras pero me aparece el siguiente error:

Warning message:
Ignoring unknown parameters: withd

¿Qué puedo hacer para solucionarlo?

Muchas gracias!

Comment: Bienvenida a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando así, tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas.

Comment: En principio lo que muestras es un warning, que eventualmente podrías ignorar, o suponiendo, por que ni siquiera sé que es lo que estás ejecutando, puede que sea un error tipográfico ¿no será que `withd`  debería ser `with`?

Comment: Hola Inés! Por favor incluye e código completo del gráfico. Como ya fue mencionado en el comentario anterior: mejorar la pregunta ayuda a quien quiere ayudarte.